# Visual Studio 2017 keeps using outdated Debug builds of referenced projects when publishing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

I have a project set up like this:

**MainProject.csproj**:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;ubuntu.16.04-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Project1\Project1.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Project2\Project2.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="mark.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Project1.csproj**:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.6;net452</TargetFrameworks>
    <OutputTypeEx>library</OutputTypeEx>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <Version>1.0.16</Version>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>True</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'">
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <DebugSymbols>True</DebugSymbols>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|netstandard1.6|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|netstandard1.6|x64'">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Reflection.Emit" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ValueTuple" Version="4.3.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Project2.csproj**:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.6;net452</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Project1\Project1.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I have configured publishing the project using `Right click -> Publish` like this:

```
Profile Name: FolderProfile
Configuration: Release
Target Framework: netcoreapp1.1
Target Runtime: win10-x64
Target Location: bin\Release\PublishOutput\Win10
```

Whenever I try to publish the project (in release mode), Visual Studio decides to use old Debug-builds of `Project1` and `Project2` instead of the new Release builds. I have traced the issue to the Roslyn csc command that Visual Studio is executing. In the output console I see this:

```
[ Build output of all Release builds ]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe /noconfig /unsafe- /checked- /nowarn:1701,1702,1705,2008 /nostdlib+ /platform:x64 /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:TRACE;RELEASE;NETCOREAPP1_1 /errorendlocation /preferreduilang:en-US [...] /reference:D:\Workspace\MySolution\Project1\bin\Debug\netstandard1.6\Project1.dll /reference:D:\Workspace\MySolution\Project2\bin\Debug\netstandard1.6\Project2.dll [...]
```

Note how it's actually using the `bin\Debug` files instead of the `bin\Release` files.

How do I force Visual Studio to use the Release builds instead of the outdated Debug builds when publishing?

Comment: On the Solution, try right-click, Properties. Switch 'Configuration' to Release. Check that all Projects are using theire 'Release'. Make sure to choose the platform correct as well. Helped me once on a normal 4.x Solution.

Comment: @PatrickArtner all projects are set to `Release` and `Any CPU`, that's what it should be, right?

Comment: If you are Publishing AnyCpu & ReleaseI think you should be fine - luck with finding the culprit.

Comment: How did you get Project1.csproj like that? I don't think you should have anything like `<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'">`. Such property group tags should no longer appear in the new projects.

Comment: @LexLi VS is adding them automatically when I change something in the project properties page.